# Как завершить поток?

Tags: android, java

Я расширил базовый класс Thread.
В run приведен следующий фрагмент:

```
while(Flag)
{
Socket sock=serverSocket.accept();
...
...
...
}
```

Ну, Flag это, думаю понятно, что флаг работы потока, но он не работает, когда serverSocket ожидает подключение. Посоветуйте, как организовать прерывание потока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)

```
void    interrupt()  // Interrupts this thread.  
static boolean  interrupted()  // Tests whether the current thread has been interrupted.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.interrupted()
```